# What is the best approach to write hooks?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I had to use some hook functions on almost every project I worked, right now I am working on a project ( basically to collect donations and maintain organizations list ) where I need to write lots of custom code, at first I started to write all the code in theme i am developing, later I realized that its not going good with all the functions in theme because **some hooks need to be written in modules** so now some of the code is written in module and some is in theme which breaks the functionality when switch theme or with admin theme.

So I am thinking to write all the code again but not sure what is the best approach to write custom code in a drupal project.

if all code goes in custom module some of the theme sections needs to be rebuild and I didnt find any proper article on net on this

Answer (score -1):

I think your question is more of in-general type . Please specify for what all purpose you need to use hooks .
I think this might be helpful for you : http://www.stephanemartinw.com/articles/25-theme-drupal-hooks-templates-functions

Thanks